# How to handle integer overflows with atomic increment and compare-and-swap operations?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I am writing a bit of code that implements an (unsigned) integer counter.

1. It is used from an arbitrary number of threads.
2. A thread should get a unique value every time until overflow.
3. If integer type range is overflown, zero should be returned.
4. I have at my disposal atomic increment function (returns old value), and atomic compare-and-swap function.

All scenarios I have come up with so far suffer from race conditions on overflow. Is it possible to implement the counter with these constraints?

Comment: using cas you can check before the cas if the value has reached max. Alternatively use 'long long' and 64 bit cas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build everything from compare-and-swap. The general algorithm is

```
int DoSomeAtomicCalculation()
{
    static int value;
    int capture, newValue;
    do {
        capture = value;
        newValue = some_function_based_on(capture);
    } while (!compare_and_swap(value, capture, newValue));
    return newValue;
}
```

(I'm assuming that `compare_and_swap` takes a variable, a comparison value, and a swap value, and it returns `true` if the comparison succeeded (and the swap occurred).

Comment: Of course! For some reason I forgot the "compare" part of "compare and swap".

Comment: It's the lack of caffeine :) Brain stops running on all cylinders.

Comment: You could also use inline asm with atomic increments and check the overflow flag on EFLAGS